# How to override a dependency chart version defined in requirements.yaml in helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Looks like there is a request for this (link below) but the issue is still in open state:

https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2205

I was wondering if there is any workaround so that I can pull a chart from chart museum and override one or more versions via command line to point to a different version?

Comment: AFAIK the only workaround is keeping a local modified copy of the chart.